# maxima of a trigonometric function

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

What's the maximum value of $\sin^4(x)+\cos^4(x)$ .I think the answer is $1$ but I want to prove it with AM-GM inequality ie without calculus.

Comment: This doesn't use the AM-GM inequality explicitly, but note that since $-1 \leq \sin x \leq 1$, we have $$\sin^4 x \leq \sin^2 x$$ and similarly for cosine. Thus, $\sin^4 x + \cos^4 x \leq \sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:
$$\sin^4x+\cos^4x=(\sin^2x+\cos^2x)^2-2\sin^2x\cos^2x=1-\dfrac{(2\sin x\cos x)^2}2$$

Now use $\sin2u=2\sin u\cos u$

and $\cos2y=1-2\sin^2y\iff2\sin^2y=1-\cos2y$

finally utilize: for real $A,-1\le\cos A\le1$

Comment: Simpler perhaps to note $1-2(\sin x \cos x)^2 \le 1$ with equality iff $\sin x =0$ or $\cos x=0$.

Comment: @Macavity, Agreed, but the current solution will provide minima as well